# How to create keystore (.pfx) file

Tags: java, openssl, keytool

I have newly purchased RAPID  wild card SSL certificate with me.
Now i want to generate keystore(.pfx) file. 
Could anyone please help me and tell me what is the step for the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the [this link](http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/creating-your-own-test-certificates-and-keys-for-signing-pdf-files/).

In Windows open a console window, cd to somewhere sensible and type:

```
cipher /r:whateveryoulike
```

Enter a password and you have a certificate (whateveryoulike.cert) and a .pfx file (whateveryoulike.pfx).